# what should I put in name value pair of update environment variable in power devops tool of pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am a little bit confused what should I put in the update environment variable?

[image: Update Environment Variable]

How can I update the environment variable of the solution in Azure pipeline?
Steps that I followed

1. Created solution in power app.
2. Created canvas app within solution and set allow to "Automatically add environment variables when adding data sources" from **General Setting**.
3. Added SharePoint Data Source list in canvas app
4. Created Build and Release Pipeline using PowerDevops tools
5. Used Update environment variable agent job within release pipeline
   how do I use update environment variable or is there any way to update environment variable?